# Is it a good idea for white to play the Botvinnik system in the Sicillian defense?

Tags: opening, sicilian-defense, english-opening

After 1. e4 c5, the following line is not popular:

```
[fen ""]
[startply "3"]

1. e4 c5 2. c4 Nc6 3. Nc3 g6 4. g3 Bg7 5. Bg2 d6 6. Nge2 e6
```

Is there any reason that this line is not frequently played?

Comment: i think this is a reasonable approach for english players. playable

Comment: Problem of the Botvinnik is that you fight for equality at most. There are some tricks and threats, but it's easier to lose than to win the game.

Answer (score 1):

this variation seems to make an equivalence for both sides but the reason this is not much popular imo is because:
1.you have given up the control over d4 square which is a key square
2.your opponent's fianchetto bishop is much more active than yours because of the pawn in e4 and you cannot immediately perform ideas such as d2-d4-d5 and you should spend a lot of tempo for d3-Be3-d4 while black can safely castle and develop and is in no trouble

Answer (score 1):

The move allows equality for black and nothing more, but the reason you don't see this being played often is that an e4 player would not generally want to transpose to a system outside the scope of the regular positions they face. You don't get that pawn structure in any other e4 opening so your understanding of it would be limited.
Also note that the key tenet of the Sicilian and up to a certain degree, the caro kann, is that black opens with a flank pawn, letting white develop an initiative, secure in the fact that their position is genrally solid and that the endgame will be fruitful for them as they have an extra central pawn (open Sicilian and exchange caro and some lines of advance caro kann)
Also worth noting is that a "pure" botvinnik, with the knight of E2 is not as good in this line(symmetrical English) compared to a botvinnik-like setup  with Nf3 (check tony kosten's book "the dynamic English" for more on this)

Comment: Do you get the pawn structures in the Open Sicilian in other 1.e4 openings then?

Comment: There are 2 main pawn structures seen in the open Sicilians, there's the scheviningen centre with e6/d6 and the boleavasky hole with d6/e5. The difference between the botvinnik structure obtained here and these 2 open Sicilian pawn structures is that you can get those pawn structures with various Sicilians for eg, kalshnikov and sveshnikov both lead to a boleavsky hole while the botvinnik structure is unique in that regard

Answer (score 0):

It's a fine approach but you need to know what to do if Black just copies the setup which is a recommended approach in some books.